# If Statement for When button is clicked

Tags: vba

I am trying to write an If statement in VBA that is somewhat in this format:

If Button A is clicked
Then
Open a file
End If

I am stuck at the first part where I am not sure how to write the portion for the "If Button A is clicked". Would greatly appreciate any advice on this.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvQlz.png)

The expected result would be that the file opens when the user presses button A and specifies the location of the file that is to be opened.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog

Comment: Buttons typically generate an event when they are clicked - you would use that event to run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A button being clicked is an ephemeral event that happens, not state that you can test with an "if". Set an event handler to call the code when the button is clicked, and don't worry about an "if".

Comment: Hi Joseph, sorry do you mind explaining what you mean? I am quite new to VBA, so I do not quite understand what you were trying to say

Comment: I dare to rephrase and explain what Joseph said. Button is not a switch. It does not have a toggle status like "On" and "Off". The way you asked your question it seems you are trying to come up with a `If` statement that tests the status of the Button ("On" or "Off") and then Opens file based on this. It is not possible because button is not a switch. It produces very quick, momentuous event when you click on it. Joseph tells you that all you need to do is to write a macro to Open the File and then assign it to the button. Thus, when you click the button, file opens.